# Difference between Blender 2.8’s camera and world HDRI

Tags: 3d-view, hdri

Does one of you know whats the difference between *Camera HDRI* and *World HDRI*

[image: Lights panel in Blender 2.8's Preferences]

---

Blender 2.8 now have these options to import *Viewport HDRIs*

I've noticed that if i import a file (either *.hdr*, *.exr*, *.png*, and *.jpg*) as "**camera HDRI**", it **only** is shown as a Studio Light on **Solid Mode**

[image: Imported camera HDRI, showing only in Solid Mode Studio Light]

While importing as "**world HDRI**" it works **both** in **Solid** Mode's StudioLight and **LookDev** (Material) Mode

[image: Imported world HDRI, showing both in Solid Mode Studio Light and LookDev]

So...
What's the purpose of have those two ways to import HDRs? Is it a bug, that, being each import mode work only for one Lighting type, make "World HDRI" work for Solid mode too?

---

**edit**

This question was also posted on Blender Artists
Got an awesome answer there, and make it clear
Here's the link to the topic: https://blenderartists.org/t/differece-between-blender-2-8s-camera-and-world-hdri/1117783

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well since you seem to have [cross posted this](https://blenderartists.org/t/differece-between-blender-2-8s-camera-and-world-hdri/1117783) I'll just shamelessly plagiarize Brecht's answer for completeness sake.

Camera HDRIs are basic studio lights meant for fast performance with non realistic shading.

They will behave like matcaps in the sense that they are viewpoint dependent and will rotate along with the view angle.

World HDRIs behave as realistic environment maps like the ones you would use in Cycles World environment textures.

They are convenient scene lighting replacement suitable for quickly testing your model and viewing it under different lighting conditions.

Both can be easily easily user customized by adding new entries to the menu either from the user preferences by pressing the small Wrench icon, or by manually adding files to the folder `Blender-2.80\2.80\datafiles\studiolights`, either under a `Camera`, `Matcap`, or `World` subfolder.

> [By *Brecht*](https://blenderartists.org/t/differece-between-blender-2-8s-camera-and-world-hdri/1117783/2?u=dphantom)
>
> Camera HDRIs are like matcaps or solid mode lighting in 2.7x, in that
>   they rotate along with the camera. This ensures objects are always
>   well lit and you can see their shape clearly, even if it’s not
>   realistic.
>
> World HDRIs are the same as environment textures in the world, with
>   light coming from the same global direction. This is the more
>   realistic method, and the only one that can be efficiently supported
>   for features like Eevee indirect light and light probes. For that
>   reason camera HDRI’s are not available in LookDev shading mode.
>
> Naming of these features could be improved.

Comment: Yeah. The conversation had really well there. Now i understand it.

For those who want to see, here's the link again:
https://blenderartists.org/t/differece-between-blender-2-8s-camera-and-world-hdri/1117783