# Background reflected in glossy glass, but I didn't set it

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've made a roughness 0 glass pane, when I'm in lookdev mode it's reflecting a background that I didn't put there. I know I could just ignore it, but I'd rather be able to see what it'll mostly look like when I'm in the later stages. I also just want to know how on Earth I managed to set this background without realising it

Reflection completely ignores any objects I put in front of it. If I placed this glass inside my house, it would still just reflect trees (This is the point where I felt I couldn't ignore it - reflections are going to play a big part in my project and I don't want to be in render mode all the time)

The nodes are the default glass BSDF, except I set roughness to 0

The glass is set to 20mm thick, if that makes a difference

The background moves with my perspective and moves when I relocate the glass

I have a few HDRI's on my PC, but none look remotely like this

Also, I'm using cycles as I find Evee buggy as hell

[image: Image in LookDev]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/112297/599

Answer (score 4):

Lookdev mode uses Eevee under the hood overrides certain lighting parameters for a faster, simpler preview. The idea is for it to provide a reasonably general lighting setup out of the box without needing configuration, enabling users to quickly develop how their materials look.

You may find the following questions also relevant:
[Differece between Blender 2.8’s camera and world HDRI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112297/differece-between-blender-2-8-s-camera-and-world-hdri)
[How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128499/how-to-use-2-8s-default-hdris-in-renders)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of pre-loaded HDR envirionments for DevLook.

You can select them in the viewport shading area :

[image]

If you have your own HDR and load it as Environment texture in the world settings, then you can select **Scene World**.

Answer (score 2):

That is the default preview environment which comes with Blender 2.8. You can pick a different one via the drop down next to the shading buttons in the header:

[image]

They are intended to give a quick way to check how a given material looks under different lighting conditions. If you check *Scene World*, the environment configured via the world material settings is used instead.