# How do i remove the the default HDRI in Blender 2.8 eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hdri

I'd like to get a studio type of reflections. Seems that the HDRI default is reflecting on my model. I'd like to have the basic lighting setup for my model. Is there a way to disable the HDRI?

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134736/background-reflected-in-glossy-glass-but-i-didnt-set-it/142014#142014

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any HDRI applied when creating a new project. You can set your own HDRI or change an existing one in the world tab. If you want to remove an existing HDRI you delete the nodes connected to the color socket or change the texture to one you like better.

[image: World tab]

Click on the button behind the color field.

[image]

Select environment texture from the dropdown. This will allow you to select an image that is used as background.

[image]

Click on Vector and select the Mapping node. This allows you to change the orientation of the HDRI.

[image]

Click on the Vector socket of the Mapping node and select Generated from the dropdown. You select and .hdr or .exr image to light your scene

[image]

Example of how it could look like.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I wanted to do, is to get rid of the reflective environment light and have a studio lighting instead (just like the previous blender versions. Here i have the lmage of the issue, where i just changed the material in to chrome. https://imgur.com/J0r0laM

Comment: Could it be that the image is part of the material? You don't have an environment texture applied to the world. Or is there a script/addon running that adds this?

Comment: I dont think so. Its persisting on all objects that i put on.